# Making an image "move" on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I am trying to make an image appear as if it is moving across and canvas and restore the previous background when its next drawn.

The following test worked when drawing a basic rectangle.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 10,  = 10, w = 50, h = 50;
var vx = 2;
var vy = 2;
var back = ctx.getImageData(1,1,1,1);
function draw() {
  ctx.putImageData(back,x, y);
  x += vx;
  y += vy;
  back=ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}
setInterval(draw, 1000/60);
```

However when substituting the rectangle for an image as follows, it doesnt appear to show point.png and instead the imagedata for "back" appears to move.

```js
 var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var x = 10,
   y = 10,
   w = 50,
   h = 50;
 var vx = 2;
 var vy = 2;
 var back = ctx.getImageData(1, 1, 1, 1);

 function draw() {
   ctx.putImageData(back, x, y);
   x += vx;
   y += vy;
   back = ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h);
   var img = document.getElementById("point");
   ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
 }
 setInterval(draw, 1000 / 60);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: The more customary canvas pattern is to: (1) have 2 images--the background and the moving object,  (2) clear the canvas completely, (3) redraw the background, (4) redraw the moving element in its new position on the canvas. In terms of performance, using drawImage is much more preferable to getImageData / putImageData.

Comment: I have tried that first, however all the other images which are drawn on the canvas appear to flicker constantly as a result.

Comment: You can reduce the flicker by setting the background image as the background image to the canvas or by "layering" your canvas over an image object containing the background image. This layering can be done using a Div containing the img and canvas elements (div is postion:relative and the img / canvas elements are position:absolute). ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the console, you should see something like that

```
`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`
```

Once you have inserted some external datas in the the canvas, you can not access to its contents anymore. 
The image must have the same origin as the page.